# How to copy a folder x number of times in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, copy

I have a this little script that just copies a folder right now:

```
$NumberOfProfiles = Read-Host "Enter the number of Portable Firefox profiles You need:"
$WhereToWrite = $Source 
$Source = Get-Location 
$FolderName = "Apple"
$SourceDirectory = "$Source\$Foldername\*"
Copy-Item $SourceDirectory $WhereToWrite -Recurse
```

But I'd need it to copy x times that is defined in `$NumberOfProfiles` with `Read-Host`. Also, for some reason it just copies the content of the folder itself but not the main folder.

Big thanks if anybody could lend a noobie a helping hand.

Comment: How do you want to enumerate successive copies? If you copy to the exact same destination each time it will just overwrite the same files over and over.

Comment: Just put a for-loop around the `copy-item` command and loop `$numberofprofiles` amount of times. as @TheMadTechnician said. unless you name each folder different it will just overwrite itself anyways. use `-container` in the `copy-item` command to retain folder structure

`copy-item $sourcedir $Dest -Recurse -container`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! The -container did the trick for the folder structure. But with the copying I'd like to have different folders and not overwrite themselves. Like $NumberOfProfiles = 10 and it would copy 10 folders named Apple1, Apple2 ... Apple10. Any ideas? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somnething like this would get you the apple1,apple2...Applel0

```
$NumberOfProfiles = Read-Host "Enter the number of Portable Firefox profiles You need:"
$Source = "C:\source\"
$WhereToWrite = "C:\Dest\Apple"
for($i=1;$i -le $NumberOfProfiles;$i++){
$dest = "$WhereToWrite$i"
Copy-Item $Source $dest -Recurse
}
```